# How to pull css properties along with html content in Ajax?

Tags: css, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax to pull some html code from a file 'test.txt' on the server into my webpage. How do I pull the css for that along?

```
<html>
<head>

<<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#testdiv").load("http://example.com/test/test.txt");
  });
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="testdiv">This gets populated</div>
<button>Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Content of text.txt:

```
<div id="everything">
<div id="one">
<p>Some text for div one</p>    
</div>
<div id="two">
<p>Some text for div two</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a CSS file referenced in text.txt. How do you know what CSS file to look fore?

Comment: I haven't created one yet. wasn't sure where I should reference that.

Comment: Using jQuery, you can append a CSS file to the current page: $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="someurl.css" />');

Comment: got it. thanks. On a side note, is the method I am using above the best way to do all this?

Comment: Just to load HTML, that's a fine way to do it, or you could also check out $.get, which I believe handles callback functions differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can append a CSS file to the current page:

```
 $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="someurl.css" />');
```